# Delete/clear all contents of a neptune named graph using sparql

Tags: python, sparql, amazon-neptune

I am trying to delete/clear data from a named graph using python. Used approach

```
import requests
url = "neptune_endpoint:8182/sparql"
query = "CLEAR GRAPH IRIref."
PARAMS = {"query" :query}
r = requests.get(url, params= PARAMS)
```

getting error malformed query. Thanxs in advance for help.

Comment: It looks like you are missing an end quote after `IRIref`. Can you just confirm that this is a typo and edit if so?

Comment: also what is IRIRef? if it's a non prefixed IRI, it has to be put into `<>`

Comment: @UninformedUser i have enclosed the IRIref in <>

Comment: @ValerioCocchi yes it was a typo and i have corrected it.

Comment: @UninformedUser IRIref is the named Graph URI.

Comment: So you will need to write is as `<IRIref>` then.

Comment: @sundaramShandilya can you please show the query you're really executing now? the query has to be `CLEAR GRAPH <SOME_GRAPH_IRI>` - also, it is a SPARQL Update query, thus the query param has to be `update` by default. So, you should use `PARAMS = {"update" :query}` because the overall HTTP request is basically `http://neptune_endpoint:8182/sparql?update=` and then the encoded query string resp. in your case the SPARQL update command

Comment: @UninformedUser my actual query is " CLEAR GRAPH <http://www.xyzassociation.com/ontology/pmdDevelopment#> and i tried using it update params still getting an error of InternalServerException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work for you.

```
import requests
url = "neptune_url:8182/sparql"
query = "CLEAR GRAPH IRIref"
headers = {"content-type": "application/sparql-update"}
r = requests.post(url, data=query, headers=headers)
```

Note that the specification requires this to be a POST and have specific content type headers set.  Neptune is fully SPARQL 1.1 compliant, so the relevant areas in the specification here are https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation and https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#clear.